# Magento - Trying to hide order with specific status from the sales order grid in Adminhtml

Tags: php, magento, grid, adminhtml

I am working with Magento 1.9.2 and i am working on a custom extension.

I have created a copy from

> /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

Copy to :

> /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

And then in the second one i was modifiyng this function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

To this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'epaycc'));;
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

And now i have other problem.
It seems it is not showing orders with status `epaycc` as i wanted but now it is not showing the names for the customers who created the order. Take a look:

[image]

I think the problem occur because i have not set the filter right.
Where is my mistake, how can i fix it and achieve what i want ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection() {
  $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
  $collection->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq', 'epaycc'));
  $this->setCollection($collection);
  return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        // filter ty status 
    $collection ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('neq' => 'complete'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

and it worked perfectly, showing all the columns details.